# ON/OFF switch using check box in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hi friend's i am new in laravel 5.1 how to use ON/OFF switch box in laravel 5.1,
i have try this :

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                {!! Form::label('pluss_customer', trans('noorsi.customer.pluss_customer'), array('class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                {!! Form::checkbox('pluss_customer',1,@$customer->pluss_customer, array('class'=>'cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round','id'=>'pluss_customer', 'name'=>'pluss_customer')) !!}
                </div>
                </div>
and my css code :
input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cmn-toggle + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

how to use this switch button in laravel, and how to pass the value to controller page 0s and 1s 
any one please help me friend's

Comment: Checkboxes don't send 0 or 1. If a checkbox is checked it sends `on` if it's unchecked you won't see anything in the request.

Comment: yes Daan how can i send this value for on ,off  in controller page

Comment: and also this code not working my blade form in laravel,